# jQuery Fade with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

simple question why doesn't this code work?

```
<script>
function test( jQuery ){
 $("#fade").delay(500).fadeIn(4000);
 $("#fade2").delay(500).fadein(4000);
}
$( document ).ready( test );
</script>
```

Please keep in mind that i am new to jQuery

Thanks

Comment: There is a typo: `fadein`. JavaScript is _case-sensitive_.

Comment: The `i` in `fadeIn` should be capitalized.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Can you describe what you see and what you expected?  For example, are you expecting fade2 to fadeIn to happen AFTER fade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible reason I can think of is the element is not hidden initially - for fadeIn() to work the elements has to be hidden first.

So either hide it using script

```
function test(jQuery) {
    $("#fade").hide().delay(500).fadeIn(4000);
    $("#fade2").hide().delay(500).fadeIn(4000); //typo
    //this can be shorten to
    //$("#fade, #fade2").hide().delay(500).fadeIn(4000);
}
$(document).ready(test);
```

or using css

```
#fade, #fade2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`delay()` pauses chains of methods in the queue. You could also try raw `setInterval` instead:

```
function test(){
    var animation = setInterval(function(){
        //whatever here is run after 500 ms
        $("#fade").fadeIn(4000);
        $("#fade2").fadein(4000);
        clearInterval(animation); //we prevent the loop so it only runs once
    }, 500);
}

$(document).ready(test);
```

Or something like this so you won't need to type document ready event for each method:

```
function test(){
    var animation = setInterval(function(){
        //whatever here is run after 500 ms
        $("#fade").fadeIn(4000);
        $("#fade2").fadein(4000);
        clearInterval(animation); //we prevent the loop so it only runs once
    }, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //I like this approach better.
    test();
});
```